# Как выйти из цикла в Python?

Tags: python, if, while, break

Скрипт не выходит из цикла, если ввести `0`

```py
while True:
    choice = input("Что вы сегодня хотите?\n")
    key = input("Введите порядковый номер продукта (начиная с нуля)")
    lunch[key] = choice
    n = input("Еще что-то?\n(Для ответа введите 0 или 1\nГде 0 - Нет, а 1 - Да)\n")
    if n == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы сравниваете строку с числом.
Можно либо преобразовать ввод в число:

```
n = int(input("Еще что-то?\n(Для ответа введите 0 или 1\nГде 0 - Нет, а 1 - Да)\n"))
```

Либо сравнивать переменную со строкой:

```
if n == '0':
```

Второй вариант предпочтительнее, потому что если пользователь введёт букву или другой символ, не произойдёт ошибки.

Answer (score 3):

Очень частая ошибка. Вы сравниваете разные типы данных. Необходимо привести либо к `int`, то, что вы вводите в строку, либо ноль сделать строкой

```py
#1 вариант
    n = int(input("Еще что-то?\n(Для ответа введите 0 или 1\nГде 0 - Нет, а 1 - Да)\n"))
    if n == 0:
        break

#2 вариант
    n = input("Еще что-то?\n(Для ответа введите 0 или 1\nГде 0 - Нет, а 1 - Да)\n")
    if n == '0':
        break
```

Директива `input()` возвращает тип данных строка. Следовательно, даже если в строке будет `0` он никогда не будет равен int-овому нулю. Приводите данные к одному типу и только после этого сравнивайте